# Posición de un apuntador

Tags: c++

como puedo  imprimir la posiciones de un apuntador en un arreglo.
Ejemplo.

7 8 3 4 5

y el apuntador busca el numero 4 y que imprima la posición
 del arreglo 3 que es donde se encuentra el numero 4

Comment: Los apuntadores no tienen posiciones, simplemente apuntan a datos.

Comment: Puedes recorrer el arreglo con otro puntero y cuando encuentres el elemento que buscabas, en tu caso el 4, restar los punteros: La dirección de memoria donde apunta el puntero que recorre el arreglo y que está apuntando al número 4, menos la dirección de memoria del primer elemento, te da la posición. Aritmética de punteros se llama esto. Un saludo

Comment: no entiendo aun tu pregunta que es lo que quieres la direccion en memoria o el elmento??

Comment: muchas gracias -SuperG280

Answer (score 0):

Aquí estaría el código de la búsqueda de la posición de un número o valor en un array:

```
#include<iostream> //Biblioteca donde se encuentra la función cout

using namespace std;  //uso del espacio de nombre std

#define NUM_ELEMENTS 100

int lista[NUM_ELEMENTS];

int Posicion(int valor);//Declaración del prototipo de la función.

int main(){           //inicio de la función main
    //std::cout << "Hola Mundo!";   //Imprimir en la consola
    int valor = 0;
    int posicion = 0;

    lista[0] = 7;
    lista[1] = 8;
    lista[2] = 3;
    lista[3] = 4;
    lista[4] = 5;
    lista[5] = 0;

    std::cout << "Por favor ingrese un valor para buscar su posición: " << endl; 
        cin >> valor; //Se asigna el valor 

    posicion = Posicion(valor);

    if(posicion == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Elemento no encontrado" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Posición : " << posicion << endl;
    }
    return 1;                     //Al terminar, retornar 1.

}


int Posicion(int valor)
{
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++)
     if(lista[i] == valor) return i; //Encontrado.

   //no encontrado:
   return -1;
}
```